# How to automatically run custom module CRON only?

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, magento-cron

I've to insert/update/delete some data in my custom tables in each 6HR. so  i'm using a custom module with CRON and in that module i've written script to insert/update/delete the things.

So for automatically hitting the CRON as i R&D

(**reference link:-** https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-cron-job/) and found

that **i need to follow following steps :-**

**1-** Login on the server as Super User

**2-** from the CLI,i need to hit "crontab -e"

**3-** then,i need to set following in this file

```
*/1 * * * * php -c <ini-file-path> <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run

*/1 * * * * php -c <ini-file-path> <your Magento install dir>/update/cron.php

*/1 * * * * php -c <ini-file-path> <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

**Where "ini-file-path" =>** https://nimb.ws/fx1p70

**"your Magento install dir"=>** you can get via **DIR**

**Which is exactly working for me,but by doing this indexing,orders etc crons are also automatically running but i want to run automatically my custom module "custom_cronjob" CRON only**

Here is the screenshot:-  https://nimb.ws/zoVApY

How can i achieve the same and avoid other CRONs?

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use n98-magerun2:
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

It has a command called `sys:cron:run <job-code>` that lets you run only a specific job.

If you want to run you cronjob every 6 hours, you could edit the crontab file like this:

`0 */6 * * * php -c <ini-file-path> <magento-dir>/n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run <job-code>`

Here is a `etc/crontab.xml` file that you can insert to run your cronjob every 6 hours via the default Magento 2 cron function:

````
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="my_cron_name" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\File" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 */6 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>```
````

Comment: thanks for the update,will it execute automatically?is this extesnion?is there not any simpler way to execute my custom cron only?

Comment: This is a cron, so it will execute automatically as long as your server runs crontab. No, this is not an extension, please read the readme file in the repository. I think this way is very simple, what do you expect?

Comment: I expect something like Magento 1 cron.sh.shall i need to run "sys:cron:run <job-code>" manually?i want to hit my custom module cron automatically.

Comment: You could also install the `Aoe_Scheduler` module, go to the backend, disable all cronjobs but your own, and then run the default magento cron job. Imho, this would take longer... You run `n98-magerun` from the command line, have you read the Readme? Have you read how to use `bin/magento`?

Comment: sorrry!!! not getting you.i want to run my cron in each 6HR.how can i do that in Magento 2?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to run _only_ your custom cron job, and ignore the system cronjobs. I have added a crontab file for your magento module to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89608/discussion-between-wakar-ahamad-and-simonthesorcerer).

Comment: Actually i don't want to run indexing,orders etc
i just want to run only my custom module CRON.
so according to you i need to install " n98-magerun2" and then set 
0 */6 * * * php -c <ini-file-path> <magento-dir>/n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run <job-code>

Comment: yes, "installing" n98 basically means downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cron job with custom cron group in your module.
For more details plz visit: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html